# How can i deploy two separate projects (client and server side) to the same Google App Engine project?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing an enrollment application. The client side is an Android application enabling the client to enter their information which are stored using the data storage service of the Google cloud and the images are entered are stored using the blob storage service.

The server side is J2EE application extracting the data and blobs entered previously and doing some tests such as face recognition, alphanumeric matching etc.  These tests are done asynchronously.

The problem is that these 2 processes are independent.  How can I deploy these two projects (client and server) to the same Google project, because the applications should use the same data?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. Currently you say that you want to deploy an Android project, while you mean an App Engine backend for an Android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your application, it is clear that you have 2 projects:

1. Android application
2. Server application (written with and for deployment to Google App Engine)

For the Android application, you need to publish the application to the Google Play Store or if you want to not go via the Play Store, you could look at pushing the APK in one of the static web folders inside your GAE Application.

The Google App Engine application can be deployed using its tools and hosted on .appspot.com or your own custom domain. The assumption here is that you have done the integration between your Android application and Google App Engine application via Web Services and that data entered/captured in the Android application is sent across via Web Services that are running in your App Engine application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Romin but would you explain to me the last part of your answer: How Web Services can help me to realize my object?

Comment: Web Services is a standards based and easy integration mechanism that exposes your Server side functionality to clients. In this case, assuming that you are using Google Cloud Endpoints, you would expose functionality like submitting the data, uploading the images from Android application. So when the Android app is used, users will enter their details and click maybe a submit button, this will make a Web Service call submitting your data to your Web Service. The Web Service will then employ App Engine Dataservice code to persist the data.